# ABAP CDS in S/4 HANA uses Calculation views engine?

Tags: abap, hana, cds

Anyone know if a ABAP CDS View on a S4/Hana System run at the same engine of a Calculation View of HANA?

In other words ABAP CDS View (on S4/HANA) is equal to Calculation View in Hana?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

They are separate things. You need some modifications to convert them to each other. Find a good blog post about the concepts [here](https://blogs.sap.com/2015/07/20/cds-one-model-two-flavors/).

Comment: I'm not comparing HANA CDS and ABAP CDS. I know that are different. I just want to kwon if ABAP CDS has same performance of Calculation View.

Comment: Theoretically ABAP CDS prepare DDL for DB and create views for it.So if you call these views directly you get same performance. If you call cds and view in abap, cds can be has bad performance than view. On the other hand cds engine can have caching mechanism in abap. I can say, performance can be related with your query/scenario.